# prove the following limit without evaluating the integrals explicitly

Tags: real-analysis, limits

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^2 \ln^n(x) \, dx=0$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_2^3 \ln^n(x) \, dx=\infty$

I know for #2 I need a lower estimate for the integral that is large to show that the limit is $\infty$, but I don't how to start. For #1, should I just use zero to argue $\ln(x)>0$ and proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. In the interval $[1,2]$ we have $0\le \ln x\le \ln 2\lt 1$.
2. In the interval $\frac{e+3}{2}$ to $3$, we have $\ln x\ge \ln((e+3)/2)\gt 1$.

Comment: why the interval is $\frac{e+3}{2}$ for 2?

Comment: i wanted a region of non-zero length in which the function was greater than $1$ by at least a certain definite amount. Any choice $a$, with $e\lt a\lt 3$ will do instead of $a=\frac{e+3}{2}$, but I wanted to be explicit. If after working with the hints for a while, you find one of them insufficient, please leave a message.

Comment: but the interval was set by the problem to start at 2, which wouldn't grantee the function to be greater than 1

Comment: Yes, that is true. Let $\ln((e+3)/2)=1+c$. Then the $n$-th power of the logarithm is $\ge (1+t)^n$ on the interval $[(e+3)/2,3]$. So the integral of the $n$-th power from $2$ to $3$ is greater than the length $3-(e+3)/2$ of the little interval times $(1+t)^n$. This goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.